# Discrete Fourier transform - seemingly different definitions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics, fourier-transform

I've noticed that in most sources the definition of the DFT is given by
$$F_k = DFT\{f_n\}=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}f_nW_N^{-kn}$$
where $W_N$ is the $N$th root of unity and $0\le k \le N-1$.

While in other sources the definition is
$$F_k = DFT\{f_n\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}f_nW_N^{kn}$$

Are these definitions really equal? How is this justified?

Comment: They are just different conventions, you will find there are multiple conventions in use not only for the DFT but even the vanilla FT. The main differences are the normalization and the definition of what is the forward and the backward direction of the transform. Here you have different normalization and directions of transform. For most purposes the different conventions do not matter as long as you use the corresponding inverse transforms etc.

Comment: As mentioned there's a factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ difference on each transform component as well as a phase sign change (time-reversal). Those differences are such simple operations in both domains it becomes largely a matter of convention.

Comment: Even though, I guess, we'd get different numbers in the two different cases.